# Javascript: multiple image onerror handlers

Tags: javascript, image, fallback, onerror

Looking for ways to set *multiple* fallbacks for image loading in case the original image source threw an exception.

Given an image tag such as `<img id="art">` the following JS code sets a fallback image src to `album.jpg` when the first image `cover.jpg` throws an error:

```js
var art = document.getElementById('art');

art.src = "cover.jpg";

art.onerror = () => {
    art.src = "album.jpg";
};
```

How to trigger *another* `onerror` handler that will set yet another fallback in case when `album.jpg` is missing? E.g. if loading `cover.jpg` fails, and then `album.jpg` fails too, how to set yet another fallback to e.g. `front.jpg` and so on?

Comment: Perhaps a chain of the promises should help you. Or you can use something like `new Promise().catch().catch()` where every `catch` sets another source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same onerror handler will fire multiple times, if the `src` property is updated multiple times.

```js
let art = document.getElementById('art');

let srcs = ['cover.jpg', 'album.jpg','front.jpg', 'empty.png']

art.src = srcs.shift()

art.onerror = e => {
  console.log(`failed to load ${art.src}`)
  if(srcs.length) art.src = srcs.shift()
}
```

```html
<img id="art">
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add additional `error` handlers, the single instance will fire for *every* change to the `src` attribute.

Note that this means your current code will create an infinite loop, where it changes the `src` to 'album.jpg' and that image also fails to load.

To do what you require you can test to see what the current `src` is and act accordingly. The logic flow can then be amended to prevent the infinite change/error loop by detecting the last possible image.

```js
var art = document.getElementById('art');
art.onerror = e => {
  console.log(`${e.target.src} not found`);
  
  if (e.target.src.endsWith('/cover.jpg'))
    art.src = "album.jpg";
  else if (e.target.src.endsWith('/album.jpg'))
    console.log('Last image - ending loop');  
};

art.src = "cover.jpg";
```

```html
<img id="art" />
```

Depending on how many fallback images you have, you may be better off using an array or object to list them, and working through them by index.

Comment: does it mean that image candidates for example can be defined as an array with `var imgs = ['cover.jpg', 'album.jpg','front.jpg', 'empty.png'];` and then in the `onerrror` use something like `art.src = imgs.pop()`?

Comment: Yep - that would work. `shift()` would also work if you want to work from the start of the array. You'd just need to check that the array had anything left in it to remove :)